# Javascript Login Popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can you please suggest how to handle login popup on Chrome using Selenium :

Since org.openqa.selenium.security.UserAndPassword removed from Selenium 3.0 and above, how to progress with the login ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show a picture of the popup and, if possible its Html. Otherwise it’s quite difficult to help you.

Comment: Is the site basic auth, so you can pass the username/password in the URL?

Comment: Hi, 
It is not basic auth, hence passing the username and password in the URL does not work, 
Also, please find the screenshot of the page, I apologize for scrambling the URL, however, it is a HTTPs URL .

https://ibb.co/L9sb8z4

Answer (score 0):

Check these out [1](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KxQQQml1aE).

The second video though used with Firefox explains that to pass a username and password through the url itself.  For example when calling the `driver.get()` function you can pass the username in password of the page by the following.

```
driver.get("https://username:password@domain.com")
```

Website 1 however does it by passing it through Selenium's server and lists various other methods with out using the url.

Refer to link 1's methods 2 and 3 for use without using the url method.

Comment: Passing the username and password in the URL does not work since it is not basic auth, auto IT may be an option, however inspecting the elements and filling the alert does not work on Chrome, 

Does anyone have any implementation experience

Comment: That was not the only method. Look at method 2 and 3 on the first link.

Comment: Hi, Method 3 does not work , now coming to Auto IT, I want to avoid auto IT since I would eventually run the script on Jenkins linked to an environment where I dont have much control, hence implementing auto IT would be difficult ,
Any other way that this could be handled ?